# Static C string allocation question

Tags: c, string, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```
char* str = "Hello World";
memcpy(str, "Copy\0", 5);
```

A segmentation fault occurs during the memcpy. However, using this code:

```
char str[12];
memcpy(str, "Hello World\0", 12);
memcpy(str, "Copy\0", 5);
```

The program does not produce a segmentation fault.

Does the problem arise from allocating the memory on the stack versus the data section?

Comment: Why the double nulls? A string literal already includes the terminating `\0`, as you can see with `sizeof "foobar"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use a string literal in gcc the value is placed in read-only memory and cannot be modified. Trying to modify it leads to undefined behaviour. Usually you will get a segmentation fault on Linux when you try to do this.

The second example works because you aren't modifying the string literal, you are modifying a copy of it that is stored in variable that is not read-only.

Comment: +1 The standard says (6.4.5/6) "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined." There is no mention of read-only memory though (and it may well be right for Linux and gcc)

Comment: The implication of "Hello, World" is that the array is a const char *.  Of course you can point to a const char * with a regular char *.  If you turn up gcc's warning level, it will complain about this of course.  The data is still unmodifiable, however.

Comment: @pmg: When the standard says certain behavior is undefined, that means (at least as far as the standard is concerned) a conforming implementation is allowed to do *ANYTHING*.  Reformat the hard drive, trigger thermonuclear Armageddon, etc.  If all the programmer is getting is a Segmentation Fault she's getting off easy.

Comment: In many cases the "undefined behavior" cases are those that needs hardware support. In this case it is support for memory access rights.

Comment: @KFro: String literals are of type `char [n]` in C, not `const char [n]`.  The situation is different in C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* str = "Hello World";
```

and

```
char str[12];
```

are two very different things. One allocates a pointer on the stack and an array in read-only "code segment". The pointer then points at the array. The other allocates the entire array on  the stack, and there is no pointer.

Comment: Can some one confirm this please. str is it stored in the code segment ? I think its in the data segment.

Comment: actually it's called `rdata`.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording on my part. The static constant data and code segment are separate segments. But the memory in both of them cannot be modified.

Comment: Actually it's implementation defined whether the string constant is in the code section, in a constant data section or even in a modifiable initialized data section.

Comment: @PaulStelian: very true. It still pays to know the difference, for those implementations that do make the difference important.

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes, you should, for safety concerns, consider it is within the code section.